# backend python code to send an email and print a message on the page that send the request

Tags: python, html

I have looked at all over internet but have not yet been able to find out why I am not getting the following to work. Basically I have a webserver setup where my httpd.conf is point to /var/www/html as my root. In there I have a simple form that upon "submit" will try to find "mymail.py" in /var/www/cgi-bin/ and run it.
"mymail.py, is very simple, it will create a html markup and send out an email.

However, I notice that when I run the mymail.py code by itself, an email goes out with no problem, but when I run the "mail.html" from /var/www/html, I only get the text messages printed back on the screen and the email never goes out. It is as if the mymail.py stops executing right after sending the html to the requesting page.

I have tried several ways of doing this and the result is the same. The code I am experimenting with is listed below:

### mail.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

        <title>Process the form and send an email</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <form name='feedback' method='post' action='../cgi-bin/mymail.py'      accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <input type='hidden' name='myForm' value='feedback' />
            Name: <input type='text' name='Name' size='20'/><br>
            Email: <input type='text' name='Email' size='20'/><br>
        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit It'/>
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

---

### mymail.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
import smtplib

#email components
    sender = 'me@company.com'
    receiver = ['me@company.com']
    message = """From: Me <me@company.com>
    To: Me <me@company.com>
    subject: testing email

    This is a test
    """

    #Create instance of FieldStorage

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    #Get data from fields
    name = form.getvalue('Name')
    email = form.getvalue('Email')


    try:
       print   "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
       print   "<html>"
       print   "<head>"
       print   "<title>Email Form Processing</title>"
       print   "</head>"
       print   "<body>"
       print   "<h2>Name: %s Email: %s</h2>" % (name, email)
       session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')
       session.sendmail(sender,receiver,message)
       session.quit()
       print   "</body>"
       print   "</html>"
    except    smtplib.SMTPException:
```

when the form is run, the message that the email has been sent is sent to the page but the python code that actually sends the email never happens. I do not understand where the problem is.

Comment: My guess: SELinux is blocking httpd from making email connections. (the `httpd_can_sendmail` boolean - https://sufi.io/selinux-apache-sendmail/ )

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `try`/`except` clause, or you won't be able to see what is the problem!!!

Check all your apache log files to get more info on your problem.  Thery are probably here:`/var/log/httpd`.

If you don't understand the error, try pasting it in a new question here.

(And: cgi is considered an ancient technology.  Consider moving to something a little more modern.  WSGI + [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/) could be a very easy place to start).